# XAML reader equivalent to IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, deserialization

I have added new fields to a persisted class, and need to ensure that they are set to sensible defaults when loading older versions of the XAML serialized file from disk. Previously, with the BinaryFormatter, I would use the OnDeserialization method to work out what defaults I should set if new fields have been added to a persisted class (using the OptionalField atttribute). E.g.:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs when the entire object graph has been deserialized.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The object that initiated the callback. The functionality for this parameter is not currently implemented.</param>
    public override void
    OnDeserialization
        (object sender)
    {
```

I can't seem to find anything equivalent so far when writing to a XAML file, e.g:

```
            using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
            {
                protocol = (Protocol)XamlServices.Load(reader);
            }
```

I would like to ensure that older files which don't contain the new optional fields within the Protocol type (in the example code above) have sensible default values within. I've hunted around but can't seem to find anything obvious (e.g. https://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2008/06/25/almost-everything-you-need-to-know-about-xaml-serialization-part-2/) Is there any equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XamlServices` internally uses a [`XamlObjectWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xaml.xamlobjectwriter). This type has a [`XamlObjectWriterSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xaml.xamlobjectwritersettings) parameter that includes various callbacks. These aren't exposed by `XamlServices`, but its functionality is easily replicated.

I haven't tested this extensively, but this seems to work:

```
public static object LoadXaml(TextReader textReader)
{
    var settings = new XamlObjectWriterSettings
    {
        AfterBeginInitHandler = (s, e) => Debug.Print($"Before deserializing {e.Instance}"),
        AfterEndInitHandler = (s, e) => Debug.Print($"After deserializing {e.Instance}")
    };

    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
    using (var xamlReader = new XamlXmlReader(xmlReader))
    using (var xamlWriter = new XamlObjectWriter(xamlReader.SchemaContext, settings))
    {
        XamlServices.Transform(xamlReader, xamlWriter);
        return xamlWriter.Result;
    }
}
```

`e.Instance` contains the object being deserialized. Not sure which callback is best for your purpose. They're more equivalent to the `[OnDeserializing]`/`[OnDeserialized]` attributes because they're called when the individual object is deserialized, rather than after the entire graph is complete like `IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization`.

Here is a more complete implementation of a class that provides events during serialization. `XamlObjectReader` doesn't support callbacks like `XamlObjectWriter` does, so this uses a workaround. It only raises an event before but not after serializing an object for the reasons explained in the comments.

```
public class CallbackXamlService
{
    // Default settings that XamlService uses
    public XmlWriterSettings XmlWriterSettings { get; set; }
        = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = true };

    public event EventHandler<XamlObjectEventArgs> BeforeDeserializing;
    public event EventHandler<XamlObjectEventArgs> AfterDeserializing;
    public event EventHandler<XamlObjectEventArgs> BeforeSerializing;
    // AfterSerializing event doesn't seem to be easily possible, see below

    public object LoadXaml(TextReader textReader)
    {
        var settings = new XamlObjectWriterSettings
        {
            BeforePropertiesHandler = (s, e) => BeforeDeserializing?.Invoke(this, e),
            AfterPropertiesHandler = (s, e) => AfterDeserializing?.Invoke(this, e)
        };

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
        using (var xamlReader = new XamlXmlReader(xmlReader))
        using (var xamlWriter = new XamlObjectWriter(xamlReader.SchemaContext, settings))
        {
            XamlServices.Transform(xamlReader, xamlWriter);
            return xamlWriter.Result;
        }
    }

    public string SaveXaml(object instance)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
            SaveXaml(textWriter, instance);
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public void SaveXaml(TextWriter textWriter, object instance)
    {
        Action<object> beforeSerializing = (obj) => BeforeSerializing?.Invoke(this, new XamlObjectEventArgs(obj));

        // There are no equivalent callbacks on XamlObjectReaderSettings
        // Using a derived XamlObjectReader to track processed objects instead
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, XmlWriterSettings))
        using (var xamlXmlWriter = new XamlXmlWriter(xmlWriter, new XamlSchemaContext()))
        using (var xamlObjectReader = new CallbackXamlObjectReader(instance, xamlXmlWriter.SchemaContext, null, beforeSerializing))
        {
            XamlServices.Transform(xamlObjectReader, xamlXmlWriter);
            xmlWriter.Flush();
        }
    }

    private class CallbackXamlObjectReader : XamlObjectReader
    {
        public Action<object> BeforeSerializing { get; }

        //private Stack<object> instanceStack = new Stack<object>();

        public CallbackXamlObjectReader(object instance, XamlSchemaContext schemaContext, XamlObjectReaderSettings settings, Action<object> beforeSerializing)
            : base(instance, schemaContext, settings)
        {
            BeforeSerializing = beforeSerializing;
        }

        public override bool Read()
        {
            if (base.Read())
            {
                if (NodeType == XamlNodeType.StartObject)
                {
                    //instanceStack.Push(Instance);
                    BeforeSerializing?.Invoke(Instance);
                }
                // XamlObjectReader.Instance is not set on EndObject nodes
                // EndObject nodes do not line up with StartObject nodes when types like arrays and dictionaries
                // are involved, so using a stack to track the current instance doesn't always work.
                // Don't know if there is a reliable way to fix this without possibly fragile special-casing,
                // the XamlObjectReader internals are horrendously complex.
                //else if (NodeType == XamlNodeType.EndObject)
                //{
                //    object instance = instanceStack.Pop();
                //    AfterSerializing(instance);
                //}
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this method, I've implemented it and it seems to work very well. I am curious, do you know if there something similar also for doing this before saving an object to XAML? I've tried inverting the method calls to use XmlWriter etc. but get stuck on where I should obtain the SchemaContext...

Comment: @Jeb `XamlService` just passes a `new XamlSchemaContext` to `XamlXmlWriter`. Unfortunately `XamlObjectReader` doesn't have the same kind of callbacks, but I've edited the answer with a workaround.